# Angular controller: $scope or VAR for non-view variables

Tags: angularjs

I know that I should keep my controllers lean & mean, but if I do need a variable which will not be reflected in the view, should I declare it in `$scope.` or as `var`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I declare them as var if I dont need two-way binding. When you put your data into $scope, you put a watch on them (and with this put it in the angular digest cycle) and that's redundant if you dont need to use the variable in the view. Simple rule: Don't use $scope if you dont need angular to update the view with it.

Comment: +1, but I'd like to change the rule to `always use the smallest possible scope when declaring a variable`. IMO that's a universally good idea for every language/framework.

Comment: Thanks, I had thought to use `var`. But, f.y.i, I am working my way through ng-book (https://www.ng-book.com) and it says that Angular will NOT put a watch on any scope variable that is not in the view (in fact, it doesn't need to watch {{myScopeVar}} only ng-model="myOtherScopeVar" which it is required to watch n order to provide two-way data binding). I still think `var`, though.